# How to change MTKView current drawable size

Tags: metal, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, metalkit, mtkview

Apple documentation says the `MTKView` current drawable default size is derived from the current view’s size, in native pixels. Is there any way to make `MTKView` current drawable half of the device's screen size?